# Accessing Columns 5-8 of xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

If I do `xmodmap -pke`, my output starts as follows -

```
keycode   8 =
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = 1 exclam 1 exclam exclamdown U2044 exclamdown
keycode  11 = 2 at 2 at trademark EuroSign trademark
```

AIUI the first keysym is obtained by pressing, the second with Shift, the third with Mode_switch and the fourth with Mode_switch and shift. But what about columns 5-8?

Comment: The xmodmap man page says that " Up  to  eight keysyms may be
               attached to a key, however **the last four** are not  used  in  any
               major  X  server implementation. "

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is more than a little bit late but I've had this problem today and I have it figured out.  If you look at the list given by xmodmap -pke, it starts at 8 being empty, 9 being escape, and so on.  BUT - if you look at the output of

```
showkey --keycodes  //(in a console, not a terminal - eg the Ctrl-Alt-F1 thing)
```

it says that escape is mapped to 1, and all of the keys you press will be of a value that is 8 less than what xmodmap will show you.  I can't tell you why this happens, but it does.  I hope this helps people in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You reach columns 5 and 6 with ISO_Level3_Shift and ISO_Level3_Shift+Shift respectively.. don't know how to reach columns 7 and 8..